# Redirecting Docker RUN output into x

Tags: laravel, docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, traefik

I am trying to build a traefik reverse-proxy.

Some services should register themselves by labels at their docker container.

So, for the services I wrote a function that prints out formatted labels.

```
php artisan route:export
```

-> 'some labels'

```
traefik.resource.frontend.rule=Host: localhost; traefik.anotherresource.frontend.rule=Host: remotehost;
```

In my Dockerfile for the service I need to redirect this output into the LABEL command.

Concept:

```
arg x = RUN 'php artisan route:export'

LABEL = x
```

My primary problem is to redirect the service-commands output into something, to use it for docker description at 'docker build'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is: In the deployment process i build the container. When the container is up and running i call my command and send it formatted into my dockerfile. When the system is started now, the label-commands in the dockerfile will be used.